# How to add a image in background in my view in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm trying add a image background in my viewController of my Swift app, but colorWithPatternImage is unavailable.. there are other form for this or is necessary add this into a imageView?

I'm trying make this with this code:

```
 let imageName = "image.png"
    self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithPatternImage(UIImage(named:imageName))
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use UIColor init method:

```
view.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named:imageName))
```

Comment: I would like to set image as Scale To Fill, because it gets trim the remaining image.

Comment: @yazh one of the option is to create new image which match size of your view. But much better solution would be create UIImageView with size matching size of the view and add it to the view as subview (below any other subviews). UIImageView has a property which you can set scale to fill. With UIColor(patternImage... you cannot set this.